# What is a good option to replace a daily SQL server snapshot replication job?

Tags: sql-server, replication

I am looking for a good alternative to replace SQL Server Snapshot Replication that replicates some tables to a reporting server everyday.

I'd prefer an agent job that I can schedule to run every night.

I want to completely replace replication. I am thinking of a process that can be automated to copy the tables to a new database (ETL maybe). I was hoping to get some ideas here and create a plan that can effectively do what the replication has been doing.

We'd like to consider reducing our server footprint from two servers down to one server, with a database for the production OLTP load, and a separate database for the reporting workload.

Edit/Update: I have created an SSIS package to repopulate the tables, it has been working well and updating changed records (In DEV). I will check if having both PROD & Reporting Databases on the same host adversely impact performance.

Comment: There are many ways to do this. From the dead-simple backup/restore to ETL (as suggested already), to using Availability Groups and a replica as a read-only server. One aspect is how large the database is compared to the tables that you need, and the aboslute sizes as well. In general, I'm found of the KISS principle, to keep things as simple as possible.

Comment: You're reducing server footprint, but are you increasing server capacity because you're going to be adding workload to a single server? Are you duplicating data from DB1 (Prod OLTP) to DB2 (Reporting ... OLAP?)? Are you using a SAN?

Comment: Thanks guys. We have made the new server (which will host both databases) have a higher memory and storage. The databases are two (each between 8-12GB). The idea would be to copy the tables from these to the new database on the same server on a daily basis (during maintenance hours). So far I think creating a dtsx package and setting up an agent job is the idea I have got. I would like it if there are better suggestions.

Comment: Since those aren't really large databases you could just use Backup/Restore to create a copy.

Comment: Backup/Restore has the advantage of not requiring special effort to deal with (for instance) foreign key relationships, which you have to handle when using ETL to replace or merge in data. A few years ago, I worked someplace where we had a couple of 200 GB DBs; we used backup and restore to refresh them nightly. For one or two 12 GB DBs, it really makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ETL for SQL Server can be accomplished natively using [SQL Server Integration Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services?view=sql-server-2017).  That can be scheduled using SQL Server Agent.

If you have a linked-server setup between the prod server and the reporting server, you could use it to truncate the target table(s), and repopulate them via the linked server.  I would schedule this at the reporting server end.

There are a large number of commercial and open-source products that can be used for ETL, unfortunately we frown upon creating "shopping lists" of products since those lists are subject to going out of date extremely quickly.

It's vastly simpler to setup this kind of scenario if you have two separate databases on the same server. Simply create a SQL Server Agent job that truncates the destination table, then does something like `INSERT INTO reportdb.dbo.tablename SELECT * FROM proddb.dbo.tablename`.  Don't get me wrong, there are a lot of subtle corner-cases around doing this on a single server, not least of which would be evaluating the impact of running the reporting workload on the same server as your transactional production workload.